# Explanation of: %in%

Tags: r

Hi I am subsetting (in R) some rows in a data.frame, in particular the time-point 24 as you can see from my example below. It is not really clear to me how the `%in%` works.

```
newdata <- mydata[mydata$Treatment %in% c(24), ]
```

Can someone give me an explanation? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the help file?

Comment: Did you read the description in `?"%in%"` and look at the examples? Which part was unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code basically says: put in "newdata" all the rows from treatment column that are (or  have) 24.

%in% is basically "in".

Read the documentation, this is pretty basic.